# Left join in apache beam

Tags: python, apache-beam

Which is the better way to left join following Pcollection in apache beam?

```
pcoll1 = [('key1', [[('a', 1)],[('b', 2)], [('c', 3)], [('d', 4)],[('e', 5)], [('f', 6)]]), ('key2',[[('a', 12)],[('b', 21)], [('c', 13)]]), ('key3',[[('a', 21)],[('b', 23)], [('c', 31)]])]
pcoll2 = [('key1', [[('x', 10)]]), ('key2', [[('x', 20)]])]
```

Expected outpus is

```
[('a', 1), ('x', 10)]
[('b', 2), ('x', 10)] 
[('c', 3), ('x', 10)] 
[('d', 4), ('x', 10)]
[('e', 5), ('x', 10)] 
[('f', 6), ('x', 10)]
[('a', 12), ('x', 20)]
[('b', 21), ('x', 20)] 
[('c', 13), ('x', 20)]
[('a', 21)]
[('b', 23)]
[('c', 31)]
```

I have implemented a left joiner using CoGroupByKey() and Pardo(). Is there any other method to implement left joiner in beam Python SDK?

```
left_joined = (
    {'left': pcoll1, 'right': pcoll2}
    | 'LeftJoiner: Combine' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
    | 'LeftJoiner: ExtractValues' >> beam.Values()
    | 'LeftJoiner: JoinValues' >> beam.ParDo(LeftJoinerFn())
)


class LeftJoinerFn(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LeftJoinerFn, self).__init__()

    def process(self, row, **kwargs):

        left = row['left']
        right = row['right']

        if left and right:
            for each in left:
                yield each + right[0]

        elif left:
            for each in left:
                yield each
```

Comment: It should be `for each in left[0]:` in both loops

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follwing code for using side inputs for the right side of the join, assuming the right side is always going to have one element mapped to each key which means that it is always much smaller in size than the left pcollection.

Also, if your pcollection is created by reading from an external source instead of an in-memory array, you will need to pass `right_list=beam.pvalue.asList(pcoll2)` instead of `right_list=pcoll2` to the ParDo . Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278102/3648318) for more info

```
class LeftJoinerFn(beam.DoFn):

    def __init__(self):
        super(LeftJoinerFn, self).__init__()

    def process(self, row, **kwargs):

        right_dict = dict(kwargs['right_list'])
        left_key = row[0]

        if left_key in right_dict:
            for each in row[1]:
                yield each + right_dict[left_key]

        else:
            for each in row[1]:
                yield each

class Display(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        LOG.info(str(element))
        yield element

p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

pcoll1 = [('key1', [[('a', 1)],[('b', 2)], [('c', 3)], [('d', 4)],[('e', 5)], [('f', 6)]]), \
        ('key2',[[('a', 12)],[('b', 21)], [('c', 13)]]), \
        ('key3',[[('a', 21)],[('b', 23)], [('c', 31)]])\
        ]
pcoll2 = [('key1', [[('x', 10)]]), ('key2', [[('x', 20)]])]


left_joined = (
    pcoll1 
    | 'LeftJoiner: JoinValues' >> beam.ParDo(LeftJoinerFn(), right_list=pcoll2)
    | 'Display' >> beam.ParDo(Display())
)
p.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the second collection is always smaller, an alternative approach would be to use [side inputs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-sideio). This would require making the right collection a side-input that is broadcast to all the workers, then writing a ParDo that processes elements from the left collection and reads in the right collection.

Comment: please describe further wherein how to I can join left Pcollection with the side input right Pcollection using same keys.

Comment: What if both tables are of equal size how to left join

Answer (score 0):

***left.txt***

149633CM,Marco,10

212539MU,Rebekah,10

231555ZZ,Itoe,10

***right.txt***

149633CM,Australia

212539MU,India

Code for left Join:

```
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
import apache_beam as beam

def retTuple(element):
  
  thisTuple=element.split(',')
  return (thisTuple[0],thisTuple[1:])



def jstr(j):
    import datetime
    jlist=[]
    for k in ((j[1]['left_data'])):
        if len((j[1]['right_data']))==0:
            id,name,rank=([j[0]]+k)
            json_str={ "id":id,"name":name,"rank":rank}
            jlist.append(json_str)
        else:
            for l in ((j[1]['right_data'])):
                
        # print(([j[0]]+k+l))
                id,name,rank,country=([j[0]]+k+l)
            
                json_str={ "id":id,"name":name,"rank":rank,"country":country }
                jlist.append(json_str)
    return jlist
            
table_spec = 'project:dataset.table_name'
table_schema = 'id:STRING,name:STRING,rank:INTEGER,country:STRING'   
gcs='gs://dataflow4bigquery/temp'
    


p1 = beam.Pipeline()

# Apply a ParDo to the PCollection "words" to compute lengths for each word.
left_rows = ( 
                p1
                | "Reading File 1" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('left.txt')
                | 'Pair each employee with key' >> beam.Map(retTuple)          # {149633CM : [Marco,10]}
    
               )


right_rows = ( 
                p1
                | "Reading File 2" >> beam.io.ReadFromText('right.txt') 
                | 'Pair each country with key' >> beam.Map(retTuple)                # {149633CM : [9876843261,New York]}
               )


results = ({'left_data': left_rows, 'right_data': right_rows} 
           
           | beam.CoGroupByKey()
           | beam.FlatMap(jstr)
           | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
               custom_gcs_temp_location=gcs,
            table=table_spec,
            schema=table_schema,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
       

)
)         
 
p1.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Comment: Could you edit your code to explain it a bit? "`def jstr(j)`" doesn’t say what the function does nor which kind of argument it takes.